# Google Sheets formula for “if contains” for grading multiple choice quiz

Tags: google-sheets, regex

I want to use a Google Sheets formula to correct a multiple choice survey that I built using Squarespace.  The results get dumped into Google sheets.

For example, if the respondent selects choice:

- A. then they would get 0 points
- B. then they would get 1 point
- C. then they would get 2 points

I tried to string several Regexmatch statements together such as the below but it won't work for more than one regexmatch at a time:

```
=if(regexmatch(A2, "A."), 0,) (regexmatch(A2, "B."), 1,) (regexmatch(A2, "C."), 2,)
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `=switch` :

```
=SWITCH(A1:A10,"A",0,"B",1,"C",2)
```

Result :
[image]

---

Same result with `regexmatch` :

```
=ArrayFormula(
if(REGEXMATCH(A1:A10,"A"),0,
if(REGEXMATCH(A1:A10,"B"),1,
if(REGEXMATCH(A1:A10,"C"),2,"no match")))
)
```

[image]